# Reading listbox items from 3rd party application

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, listbox

I am struggling to get listbox items from a 3rd party application. cant find away to get the list items from the listbox, have search for a week and have not find any solution.
Is there anyone that have a clue what to do.

Update!!
I struggle to get the verbose information form the listbox, shown in picture 3, red marking. When i use LB_GETTEXT i only get the first row. Is there a way to get all lines from the multi-line listbox item?
Some one up for this challenge :)

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal 
lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal 
hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) 
As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal 
hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr

Sub windows_API_Test()

Const LB_GETCOUNT = &H18B
Const LB_GETTOPINDEX = &H18E
Const LB_GETTEXTLEN = &H18A
Const LB_GETTEXT = &H189



Do
    DoEvents
    Main_window = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Select passes to be exported")
    Listbox_window = FindWindowEx(Main_window, 0&, "Listbox", vbNullString)
Loop Until Listbox_window > 0



numberofindex = SendMessage(Listbox_window, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, ByVal 0&)
TopIndex = SendMessage(Listbox_window, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0)

For i = TopIndex To numberofindex - 1
    textcount = SendMessage(Listbox_window, LB_GETTEXTLEN, i, 0)
   'space for null terminating string '\0' will be automatically added by VB
    buffer$ = Space$(textcount)
    ' pass string byval not byref
    ' also make sure that lParam of SendMessage is declared as ANY
    Call SendMessage(Listbox_window, LB_GETTEXT, i, ByVal buffer$)
    Debug.Print buffer$
Next i

End Sub
```

Info from Spy++
[image: Info from Spy++]

Listbox from 3rd party application
[image: Listbox from 3rd party application]

How to get information circled in red?
[image: Verbose information]

Comment: Can you precise your question? [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: I would not try to develop this in VBA. I get that's where you want the code eventually but it will be much easier to debug this in another language, e.g. C++. That said, I wonder why you aren't using UI Automation. Why not?

Comment: 1. Is the form picture you show us a form in CorelDRAW? 2. Please, **declare** all used variables. 3. Does your code go out from the loop? If it does, what value does `Listbox_window` window handle has? In order o see it as in Spy++, please add the next debugging line after `Loop Until Listbox_window > 0`: `Debug.print Hex(Listbox_window): Stop`. What does it return in `Immediate window` when stopped on it? Is it the handler you found using Spy++? I'm afraid it is not... According to this return, I will try guiding you further.

Comment: In general, this isn't going to work. Make sure you read the *Remarks* section in the documentation for [`LB_GETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-gettext). You may just receive a pointer that's meaningless in your process.

Comment: @FanaDuru: 1. It is not a form from CorelDRAW. 2. will declare all variables. 3. Code does go out of loop. Listbox_window shows the correct handle id. I tried adding '<Debug.print Hex(Listbox_window): Stop' Intermediate window shows the same handler as in spy++

Comment: @IInspectable Do you have other suggestions, other approaches. I really want this to work in VBA.

Comment: @FanaDuru Thanks to your little tips 'Debug.print Hex(Listbox_window): Stop' . The code start to read the first listbox window, the one that is greyed out in spy++. I added  getnextwindow and now it reads the net listbox window. No it works. Thanks.

Comment: UI Automation was mentioned already.

Comment: This was what I wanted to suggest. 1. **You do not need any loop**. It is enough to use `Main_window = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Select passes to be exported")` followed by
    `Listbox_window = FindWindowEx(Main_window, 0&, "Listbox", vbNullString)`. 2. it will return **the first list box handle**. Then, you need `GetNextWindow` API, called with second parameter as `2` (next one). Then your code looked OK. Glad you could solve the problem!

Comment: Autohotkey is a nice language for this type of automation. Might be worth considering, here's the docs for getting a control https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm.  I've used it in the past to simplify all the low level winAPI calls

Comment: @FanaDuru Now I am struggling to read all the line for the listbox items. Do you know how to do this? See picture 3 above.Help very much appreciated :)